# Django - TypeError: _clone() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to install `django_quiz` [GITHUB](https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz/blob/master/README.md) app into my `Django` project. I've done everything which is in the "Installation" readme file but it raises error:

```
return super(InheritanceQuerySetMixin, self)._clone(klass, setup, **kwargs)
TypeError: _clone() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

So I did

1. `python pip install Pillow`, `pip install django-model-utils`
2. cloned the file from GitHub into the Django folder directory (there is `manage.py`, apps dir etc.).
3. `cd django_quiz`
4. `python setup.py install`
5. added `'quiz', 'multichoice', 'true_false', 'essay'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`
6. added `url(r'^q/', include('quiz.urls'))`, into `urlpatterns` (`urls.py`)

After this, I tried to `python manage.py runserver` and the error raised. So I tried already do makemigrations but the same error happend.

Here is the whole traceback from cmd line (after `runserver`):

```
C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\si
te-packages\django_model_utils-2.0.3-py2.7.egg\model_utils\managers.py:106: Remo
vedInDjango110Warning: 'get_all_related_objects is an unofficial API that has be
en deprecated. You may be able to replace it with 'get_fields()'
  rel for rel in model._meta.get_all_related_objects()

C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\si
te-packages\django_model_utils-2.0.3-py2.7.egg\model_utils\managers.py:106: Remo
vedInDjango110Warning: 'get_all_related_objects is an unofficial API that has be
en deprecated. You may be able to replace it with 'get_fields()'
  rel for rel in model._meta.get_all_related_objects()

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x033284F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\ven
v\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\ven
v\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in
inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\ven
v\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_excepti
on
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\ven
v\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\ven
v\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\ven
v\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\ven
v\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\ven
v\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\ven
v\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_mo
dules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\ven
v\lib\site-packages\django_quiz_app-0.5.1-py2.7.egg\quiz\admin.py", line 16, in
<module>
    class QuizAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\ven
v\lib\site-packages\django_quiz_app-0.5.1-py2.7.egg\quiz\admin.py", line 29, in
QuizAdminForm
    queryset=Question.objects.all().select_subclasses(),
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\ven
v\lib\site-packages\django_model_utils-2.0.3-py2.7.egg\model_utils\managers.py",
 line 48, in select_subclasses
    new_qs = self.select_related(*subclasses)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\ven
v\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 852, in select_related
    obj = self._clone()
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\ven
v\lib\site-packages\django_model_utils-2.0.3-py2.7.egg\model_utils\managers.py",
 line 61, in _clone
    return super(InheritanceQuerySetMixin, self)._clone(klass, setup, **kwargs)
TypeError: _clone() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Go to InheritanceQuerySetMixin class in managers.py , remove arguments klass, setup from def _clone(), 
then run python manage.py makemigrations  for quiz, essay, multichoice, true_false and,
run python manage.py migrate ,and 
then finally run python manage.py runserver 8000